# jQuery clear queue when fast mouse move

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a carousel with thumbnail strip. Functionality is on hover, its main image is loaded to carousel. This is working fine. But if user moves fast on thumbs and stop on one thumb, it doesn't loaded current stopped index, but loads in between index while mouse was moving.

```
thumbnail.hover(
  function() {
   if (!$(this).hasClass('select'))
    $(this).addClass('over');
    var index = parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10);

        if(!$(this).attr('href')){
          slideshowManuallyPaused = true;
          stopSlideshow();
          var delayOfHover = setTimeout(function () {
            gotoSlide(index);       
            clearInterval(delayOfHover);
          }, 200);                              
   }
}
```

Any idea to get solve this?

Comment: define your interval outside the function and clear it each time you hover a new element.

Comment: @Syd No its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you, although I dont have all of your code:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pw3g8/)**

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var timer = null; 
    var thumb = $('.thumb');

    thumb.hover(function(){

        var i = thumb.index(this);
        console.log('over thumb: ' + i);

        $(this).addClass('over');

        timer = setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('executing code for thumb: ' + i);
        },500);


    },function(){

        var i = thumb.index(this);
        console.log('left thumb: ' + i);

        $(this).removeClass('over');
        clearTimeout(timer);
    })

})
```

html:

```
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
<div class="thumb"></div>
```